# two input type in php mysql-query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in which two text fields and one input text field. A query is created new row, and if there is one, just update.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$text = !empty($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : null;
foreach ($text as $idt => $pages) {
if ($pages != NULL) {    
$todb = $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO extendtovar (book_id, pages) 
VALUES ("' . $idt . '", "' . $pages . '") 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pages = "' . $pages . '"');
  }
 }
}   
  $todb = $mysqli->query('SELECT 
  nalvmag.id AS id,
  nalvmag.name AS name,
  extendtovar.book_id AS id2,
  extendtovar.pages AS pages
  FROM nalvmag LEFT JOIN extendtovar 
  ON nalvmag.id = extendtovar.book_id 
  WHERE nalvmag.remainder > 0
  ORDER BY name ASC');
  echo '<table class="raz">';
  while ($row = $todb->fetch_array())
  { echo '<tr><td>'.$row[id].'</td>';
      echo '<td>'.$row[name].'</td>';
      echo '<td><input type="text" name="text['.$row[id].']" value="'.$row[pages].'" maxlength="5" size="6"><br></td></tr>';
  }
    echo '</table>';    

echo'<button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button></form>';
}
```

But now I want to add one more input text field

```
echo $row[id];
echo row[name];
echo '<input type="text" name="text['.$row[id].']" value="'.$row[pages].'" maxlength="5" size="6">
echo '<input type="text" name="text2['.$row[id].']" value="'.$row[pages2].'" maxlength="5" size="6">
```

and when i update php code to

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $text = !empty($_POST['text']) ? $_POST['text'] : null;
    foreach ($text as $idt => $pages) {
    if ($pages != NULL) {    
    $todb = $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO extendtovar (book_id, pages, pages) 
    VALUES ("' . $idt . '", "' . $pages . '", "' . $pages2 . '") 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pages = "' . $pages . '", pages2 = "' . $pages2 . '"');
      }
     }
    }
```

field pages2 not update.

I can not understand how to properly change `foreach` and form a request

Comment: your first SQL statement is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Learn to how use parameterised queries and prepared statements to protect your database from theft, data corruption or even deletion by means of malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com/ for a clear explanation of the risks and also some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP/mysqli

Comment: Addressing your actual question, I can't quite see what your problem is. You say you want to add another text field. Then you show some code for adding another text field. Is there a problem with that code? What does it do? What did you expect it to do? Your desired output is unclear. I don't know what you mean by "form a request", particularly.

Comment: Update my answer. I want write data from two inpit type in my mysql table.

Comment: based on the sample HTML, the value submitted for the 2nd textbox will be available as an entry within `$_POST['text2']`.